# Automatically add routes from a firebase real time database with angular

Tags: angular, firebase, routes

I am working on a school project where were creating a website to review restaurants. We are using firebases real time database to store our restaurant information. Currently we are programmatically creating restaurant pages using the information stored in our database. We do this by manually adding the information into the database and manually adding a route into our app routing module. We just created forms that adds new information into our data base, but what I wanted to know is if it's possible to automatically create new routes using the information in our database.

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+add+dynamic+route?